# Set.contains() not working

Tags: json, duplicate-management, set, contains

My set contains custom JSON elements. When i try to use set.contains() method to check if the set has the JSON element it fails.

MY JSON DATA:

```
public uJSON(Id id,String name, Boolean manager,Id managerId){      

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.manager = manager;
        this.managerId = managerId;
}
```

My first Set `set<uJSON> sortedU` has uJSON elements in it.
My second Set `set<uJSON> secondSet` has UJSON elements too.

How to check if the element in secondSet exists in sortedU set or not. I have tried using contains method but it fails. (I am 100% sure there are duplicate elements)

APEX Code

```
for(uJSON reps : secondSet)
 {
   if(sortedU.contains(reps)){
      system.debug('Dupicate user found: '+reps);
   }
   else{
      // need to add this user to final list
       }
 }
```

My sortedU contains

> { uJSON:[id=00541000008bbbbAAA, manager=false,
>   managerId=00541000009ggggAAA, name=** Matt Tom, sortBy=name],
>   uJSON:[id=00541000008aa6aAAA, manager=false,
>   managerId=00541000008gf6zAAA, name=** Alicia Camry, sortBy=name] }

and secondSet also contains

> uJSON:[id=00541000008aa6aAAA, manager=false,
>   managerId=00541000008gf6zAAA, name=** Alicia Camry, sortBy=name]

Comment: note: If the set contains String elements, the elements are case-sensitive. Two set elements that differ only by case are considered distinct.

Comment: sortedU contains  { uJSON:[id=00541000008bbbbAAA, manager=false, managerId=00541000009ggggAAA, name=** Matt Tom, sortBy=name], uJSON:[id=00541000008aa6aAAA, manager=false, managerId=00541000008gf6zAAA, name=** Alicia Camry, sortBy=name] }




and secondSet also contains uJSON:[id=00541000008aa6aAAA, manager=false, managerId=00541000008gf6zAAA, name=** Alicia Camry, sortBy=name]

Comment: when i use set.contains it should display this duplicate right? but, its not!!

Comment: Can you please share where you declare both set and how you are populating them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [Using Custom Types in Map Keys and Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm), you need to override hashCode and equals in order to have Set work correctly with your custom class. For example:

```
public Integer hashCode() {
  return System.hashCode(id+'♥'+name+'♥'+manager+'♥'+managerid);
}
public Boolean equals(Object other) {
  uJson cmp = (uJSON)other;
  return cmp.id == id && cmp.name == name && cmp.manager && cmp.managerid == managerid;
}
```

Once properly implemented, contains should work as you expect.

Comment: return statement is throwing an error saying "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void hashCode(String) from the type String". Basically its not returning a integer value

Comment: @New Yes, it should have been System.hashcode, not String.hashCode. It's been a while since I've used this.